# Why is my Jenkins Artifactory plugin extracting ".zip" but not ".tgz" after download?

Tags: download, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, artifact

I have a Jenkins pipeline which is downloading artifacts from artifactory and then it should extract them. With `.zip` it works fine but with `.tgz` not.

In the artifactory documentation there is following snippet:

```
If true, the downloaded archive file is extracted after the download. The archived file itself is deleted locally. The supported archive types are: zip, tar; tar.gz; and tgz
```

```
13:49:50  Searching for artifacts...
13:49:56  Found 1 artifacts.
13:49:56  Beginning to resolve Build Info published dependencies.
13:49:56  Downloading 'https://artifactory.tools.xxx/my-app/1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4.tgz'...
13:49:56  Successfully downloaded 'https://artifactory.tools.xxx/my-app/1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4.tgz' to '/home/jenkins/workspace/deployment/my-app-1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4.tgz'
13:49:56  Finished resolving Build Info published dependencies.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] newArtifactoryServer
[Pipeline] newBuildInfo
[Pipeline] artifactoryDownload
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] {
13:49:57  Searching for artifacts...
13:49:57  Found 1 artifacts.
13:49:57  Beginning to resolve Build Info published dependencies.
13:49:57  Downloading 'https://artifactory.tools.xxx/my-app/1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4-cfManifest.zip'...
13:49:57  Successfully downloaded 'https://artifactory.tools.xxx/my-app/1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4-cfManifest.zip' to '/home/jenkins/workspace/deployment/my-app-1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4-cfManifest.zip'
13:49:57  Extracting Archive: /home/jenkins/workspace/deployment/my-app-1.0.4/my-app-1.0.4-cfManifest.zip
13:49:57  Finished extracting archive to /home/jenkins/workspace/deployment/my-app-1.0.4
13:49:57  Finished resolving Build Info published dependencies.
```

So how you can see, the `.tgz` is not getting extracted, but the `.zip` file does (like expected).

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to execute the plugin?

Comment: Are you using file spec? are you using the same spec for both downloads?
Is the 'explode' options set to 'true'? on both file specs?